# Point formula for polygon

Tags: math, polygon

I'm trying to generate a polygon of a variable size with canvas but I'm having trouble calculating some of it points, the ones in red here:

[image]

this is my current code:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var size = 200;

var points = [[x + (size / 2), y],
          [x + size, y + (size / 4)],
          [x + size, y + size - (size / 4)],
          [x + (size / 2), y + size],
          [x, y + size - (size / 4)],
          [x, y + (size / 4)]];
```

And I get this:

[image]

So `size / 4` and `size / 2` are wrong... Is there some kind of formula to calculate those tricky 4 points so the polygon fits perfectly a round circle?

Comment: What does `size` represent? The width of the hexagon from side to side, or corner to corner? Remember that the hexagon is made up of six 60-60-60 triangles. The length of the height of the triangle is the length of a side times `sqrt(3)/2`. If `size` is corner to corner, then that represents twice the length of the side of one of the triangles. From that information, you should be able to figure it out. Trig not needed since angles are "nice". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing is to divide 2*Pi into n even pieces and use trigonometry to get the coordinates. You should be able to translate the following Python script to a language of your choice:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi

def regularPoly(n,a,b,r):
    points = [(a,b+r)]
    theta = pi/2
    dTheta = 2*pi/n

    for i in range(1,n):
        theta += dTheta
        points.append((a + r*cos(theta), b + r*sin(theta)))

    return points
```

For example,

```
>>> hexagon = regularPoly(6,0,0,100)
>>> for x,y in hexagon: print(x,y)

0 100
-86.60254037844385 50.000000000000036
-86.6025403784439 -49.999999999999936
-1.0718754395722282e-13 -100.0
86.60254037844379 -50.00000000000012
86.60254037844395 49.99999999999985
```

When plotted, you get:

[image]

The formulas give standard Cartesian coordinates. Obviously, you can round to integers and do some change of variables to get in Canvas coordinates with (0,0) upper left corner.

Comment: thanks, so the formula is size * sin(2 * Math.PI/6). But why did you get there 50.000000000036 instead of 50 ? where do thos ...036 and ...012 come from ?

Comment: @AnnaK. Floating point calculations inevitably involve round-off error. It doesn't matter by the time you round to integer canvas coordinates. I would leave it at that, although a sufficiently interested person could delve into the algorithms used to implement `sin` and `cos` and answer the question why *those* specific round-off errors.